# Need help on NGINX full URL redirection rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, redirect, redirection

I am trying to redirect in a complete URL, including every strings on the url.


I want this

`http://www.SITE-A.com/everything?complete=url&fully=redirected`

redirects to

`http://www.SITE-B.com/everything?complete=url&fully=redirected`

This works ok with apache using

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.site-b\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

I did everything I found on serverfault but no luck yet.
All I can get is always this redirection

`http://www.SITE-A.com/everything?complete=url&fully=redirected`

redirects to

`http://www.SITE-B.com/?complete=url&fully=redirected`

'**everything**' is gone after redirection

I've tried these

`location /quick-search {
   try_files $uri http://www.site-b.com/quick-search.php?$arg_q;
}`

and

`location / {
   rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.site-b.com/$1 permanent; 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your Apache rewrite rule, you're trying to rewrite the host portion for any request.

A common idiom in to achieve this with NGINX is to use `server` blocks and `return`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site-a.com;

    return 301 http://www.site-b.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site-b.com;

    [...your config...]
}
```

This is the fastest way to do this, as highlighted in: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Answer (score 0):

Location directives do not take into account the query string (everything after the ?). So you need to check for this separately within the location block, possibly using if and $args.

- https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/
- https://coderwall.com/p/rqdrwq/nginx-conf-query-string-processing